# DateTime.Now is throwing an exception

Tags: .net, exception, datetime

I am getting an exception thrown on DateTime.Now on our server running a few websites. This has now happened twice to me in the past 3 days. Really strange. I am wondering whether this has started to happen with the latest Windows Update and if any of you have seen similar behaviour coming in.

The exception thrown is:

```
BASE EXCEPTION:
  TYPE: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
  MESSAGE: Value to add was out of range.
Parameter name: value
  STACK TRACE:
   at System.DateTime.Add(Double value, Int32 scale)
   at System.TimeZoneInfo.TransitionTimeToDateTime(Int32 year, TransitionTime transitionTime)
   at System.TimeZoneInfo.GetDaylightTime(Int32 year, AdjustmentRule rule)
   at System.TimeZoneInfo.GetIsDaylightSavingsFromUtc(DateTime time, Int32 Year, TimeSpan utc, AdjustmentRule rule, Boolean& isAmbiguousLocalDst)
   at System.TimeZoneInfo.GetDateTimeNowUtcOffsetFromUtc(DateTime time, Boolean& isAmbiguousLocalDst)
   at System.DateTime.get_Now()
   at (my code).FrontEnd.FrontEndPage.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in (my code file)\code\presentation\FrontEndPage.cs:line 118
   at (my code).purchase.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in (my code file)\purchase.aspx.cs:line 94
   at System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

The code where this happens is the first line in the if-statement:

```
HttpCookie loggedIn = Request.Cookies[Config.Instance.LoggedInCookieName];
if (loggedIn != null)
{
    loggedIn.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(4);
    Response.Cookies.Add(loggedIn);
}
```

Although there is an AddHours in there and the exception is talking about DateTime.Add, I don't believe it has anything to do with the AddHours, but is caused by the call to Now as you can see in the stack trace.

The server I am on is running Windows Server 2003, and is running the English (United Kingdom) locale.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Sounds like either a dodgy Windows Update that caused it or a corrupted installation of .NET really...

Comment: Can you provide the full stack trace?  Maybe this has something to do with it? http://blog.brianhartsock.com/2009/02/21/systemargumentoutofrangeexception-at-systemwebhttpcachepolicyutcsetlastmodifieddatetime-utcdate/

Comment: I know this may seem unlikely, but is the system time set correctly?

Comment: same problem in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678681/argumentoutofrangeexception-on-cookiecontainer-getcookiesuri-uri, can you add the full stacktrace?

Comment: That exception would get thrown if the conversion happening in TransitionTimeToDateTime tries to add or subtract more than 10,000 years to the DateTime. Odd.

Comment: I have included the full stack trace. It might help. Thanks for the suggestions. As an additional piece of info: DateTime.Now happens a lot in this application with storing data in the underlying database. With having only 2 errors in 3 days that means this is happening very rarely.

Comment: It happens in code that adjusts the local date/time for daylight savings transitions from the UTC time.  The transition rules are read from the registry, weirdo problems like this are often corrupt registry problems.  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones registry key.

Comment: I have looked at the registry and there are a whole lot of entries in there. How would I find out whether anything is corrupted there?

Answer (score 1):

Reviewing the code in Reflector, your exception is occurring when an in-lined `AddDays` is given bad data in `TransitionTimeToDateTime`.

Both occurrences of `AddDays` process `transitionTime.DayOfWeek` where `transitionTime` is `rule.DaylightTransitionStart` or `rule.DaylightTransitionEnd` from `GetDaylightTime` (as well as `time.DayOfWeek`, but this is always `Mod 7`).

This seems to mean `GetTimeZoneInformation` is occasionally returning bad data where the `AdjustmentRule` is generated in `GetOneYearLocalFromUtc` which calls `GetCurrentOneYearLocal`.

Because it is happening rarely, I don't think it will be due to a corrupt registry (I'd expect it to happen every time.), but to help further checking the MSDN documentation for [TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725481%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) describes the registry entries to check.

<sub>Note this information is not cached and is retrieved every time you call `DateTime.Now`, (which is of course the correct thing to do as DST could have just changed, or the user could have changed the current time zone) a good excuse for some premature optimisation by using `DateTime.UtcNow` as much as possible and applying `.ToLocalTime` only when you need to display the time to the user.</sub>