# Private method as assembly's first method in call stack

Tags: .net, datetime, vsto, encapsulation

The following exception was recorded in the log on a client system.

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Value to add was out of range.
Parameter name: value
  at System.DateTime.Add(Double value, Int32 scale)
  at ButtonPressed()
  at MessageEvent(MessageEventArgs e)
```

The custom method is fairly simple

```vb
Public Sub ButtonPressed
    If mWindows.Count > 0 AndAlso mLastEvent.AddSeconds(1) > Now
        PostMessage(New IntPtr(mHwnd), 1125, UIntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero)
    End If
End Sub
```

I am having troubles to explain how such a call stack is at all possible since `DateTime.Add(Double value, Int32 scale)` is a private method and not called by my code.

[DateTime.Now is throwing an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10323881/datetime-now-is-throwing-an-exception) seems to give an explanation for this in multi-threaded environments. But there is no call to `DateTime.get_Now` on my call stack so is it really the same root cause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the JIT has inlined the `AddSeconds` method, that's all.

For example, consider this very simple code:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var max = DateTime.MaxValue;
        var oops = max.AddSeconds(1);
    }
}
```

On my .NET 4.5 machine, that generates a stack trace of:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException:
   The added or subtracted value results in an un-representable DateTime.
Parameter name: value
   at System.DateTime.AddTicks(Int64 value)
   at Test.Main()
```

Note the lack of an `AddSeconds` call. Now it's not the exact same trace as you're seeing, but that may well be due to framework version differences.

I suggest you log `mLastEvent` at the start of the method - my guess is that you'll find that's close to `DateTime.MaxValue`.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense! I don't really think that `AddSeconds` is causing the problem since `mLastEvent` is either set to `MinValue` or `Now` and the exception message is slightly different (un-representable DateTime vs. value out of range). But `get_Now` may get inlined just the same, I guess.

Comment: Looks like you were right in the first place, I have now recorded the full stack trace including `AddSeconds` in debug mode. It's still weird to see the exception but now it is easy to work around. Thanks again.